# while doing kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 master

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, kubernetes

when i run kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16, i get stuck at [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
and get output:

[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
        - 'systemctl status kubelet'
        - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI, e.g. docker.
Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
        - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
        Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
        - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster

Apr 29 13:55:34 localhost kubelet[4129]: W0429 13:55:34.837653    4129 cni.go:213] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d

Apr 29 13:55:35 localhost kubelet[4129]: E0429 13:55:35.610791    4129 kubelet.go:2170] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized